# oneAPI successfully installed but vtune won't run

Tags: linux-kernel, windows-subsystem-for-linux, intel-vtune, intel-oneapi

I'm using windows' ubuntu terminal, which i'm sure in the problem, but I've installed the linux version of intel's oneAPI on the ubuntu terminal. its says Intel's oneAPI base toolkit has been installed, but typing either

```
vtune-gui
```

or just

```
vtune
```

into the same terminal where i just installed it gets me a "command not found" message

Comment: The Intel's OneAPI toolkit just works fine for me on the fly! May I know what machine configuration and versions of OS are you working on? Please check if other linux commands/tools are working fine on the same session/terminal, before debugging the one API toolkit

Answer (score 4):

Did you set-up ("source") oneAPI command line environment? More specifically:

For root or sudo installations:

```
. /opt/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

For normal user installations:

```
. ~/intel/oneapi/setvars.sh
```

In general, please follow [oneAPI "Getting Started"](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-intel-oneapi-base-linux/top/before-you-begin.html) guide, where you can find full list of possible prerequisites (including the one regarding setvars script), although in practice not all of them are required, depending on your usage model.

Specifically for Intel VTune or Intel Advisor GPU side analysis you may need to additionally follow "disable hangcheck" and "add user to videogroup" steps from the aforementioned guide.